Tests for Express middleware fail despite correct function execution
I'm writing tests for an Express middleware function addPagination, which sets a pagination object on the req object. The middleware works correctly during manual testing and in the application, but my Jest tests fail. I've added console.logs inside the middleware, and they show that all logic paths are executed as expected during testing.
//other imports...
import { standardResponse } from "@utils/responses";
import { normalizeError } from "@toolbox/common/errors";
import { paginationValidations } from "src/validators/pagination.validator";
import validationResultFormatter from "src/validators/validationResultFormatter";

export const addPagination = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  Promise.all(paginationValidations.map((validation) => validation.run(req)))
    .then(() => {
      const errors = validationResultFormatter(req);
      if (!isObjectEmpty(errors)) {
        res.status(400).json(standardResponse({ isSuccess: false, res, message: "Validation error.", errors }));
        return;
      }

      const { page = 1, pageSize } = (req as unknown as RequestWithQuery<PaginationParamsType>).query;
      req.pagination = {
        skip: (page - 1) * pageSize,
        take: pageSize,
        page: page,
        pageSize: pageSize,
      };

      next();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      log.error(error);
      res
        .status(500)
        .json(
          standardResponse({ isSuccess: false, res, message: "Failed to fetch company.", errors: normalizeError(error) })
        );
      return;
    });
};

All the tests below fail:
//other imports...
import { addPagination } from "src/middleware/pagination.middleware";
import { standardResponse } from "@utils/responses";
import validationResultFormatter from "src/validators/validationResultFormatter";

jest.mock("@utils/logger");
jest.mock("src/validators/pagination.validator", () => ({
  paginationValidations: [{ run: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined) }],
}));
jest.mock("src/validators/validationResultFormatter", () => jest.fn());
(validationResultFormatter as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => []);

const mockRequest = (query = {}): Partial<Request> => ({ query });
const mockResponse = (): Partial<Response> => {
  const res: Partial<Response> = {};
  res.status = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);
  res.json = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(res);
  return res;
};

describe("addPagination", () => {
  let req: Partial<Request>;
  let res: Partial<Response>;
  let next: NextFunction;

  beforeEach(() => {
    req = mockRequest();
    res = mockResponse();
    next = jest.fn();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it("should call next when no validation errors are found", async () => {
    (validationResultFormatter as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue([]);
    req.query = { page: "2", pageSize: "10" };

    await addPagination(req as Request, res as Response, next);

    expect(validationResultFormatter).toHaveBeenCalledWith(req);
    expect(req.pagination).toEqual({
      skip: 10,
      take: 10,
      page: 2,
      pageSize: 10,
    });
    expect(next).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it("should return 400 when validation errors are found", async () => {
    (validationResultFormatter as jest.Mock).mockReturnValue([{ field: "pageSize", message: "Page size is required." }]);

    await addPagination(req as Request, res as Response, next);

    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(400);
    expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      standardResponse({
        isSuccess: false,
        res: res as Response,
        message: "Validation error.",
        errors: [
          {
            field: "pageSize",
            message: "Page size is required.",
          },
        ],
      })
    );
    expect(next).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it("should return 500 on promise rejection", async () => {
    const error = new Error("Something went wrong");
    const mockRun = jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(error);
    jest.mock("src/validators/pagination.validator", () => ({
      paginationValidations: [{ run: mockRun }],
    }));

    await addPagination(req as Request, res as Response, next);

    expect(log.error).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(500);
    expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      standardResponse({
        isSuccess: false,
        res: res as Response,
        message: "Failed to fetch company.",
        errors: expect.any(Object),
      })
    );
    expect(next).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});

It seems like none of the mocked function calls are being made:
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)   
Expected: {"query": {"page": "2", "pageSize": "10"}}
Number of calls: 0
    
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
Expected: 400
Number of calls: 0
    
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
Expected: [Error: Something went wrong]
Number of calls: 0

Why are my Jest tests failing to detect the expected calls even though the middleware works correctly? Is there an issue with how I'm mocking dependencies or setting up the test environment?
